# Hosting a keystonejs app with openshift

Tags: openshift, keystonejs

I keep getting a 503 but no errors in the log when trying to host my keystone.js app on openshift, has anyone successfully hosted a keystone app with them?  Everything works fine on localhost.

I am using a fresh install of keystone.js with no blog or cloudinary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your providing very little information to give you a definitive answer. What options are you passing to `keystone.init()`? Are you using `dotenv`? If so, what are you setting there? Did you set any environment variables using `rhc set-env`?

I ask because a common (though not by far the only) culprit of 503 errors in Node.js applications on OpenShift is a port number overriding OpenShift's. Keystone looks at `process.env.PORT` before it looks at `process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT`. So, if you have `PORT` set on your `.env` or with `rhc set-env` it will take precedence over `OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT`.

I came across a similar question on the [KeystoneJS Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keystonejs/FINaQduaiIc). In that other case the developer had added a MONGODB cartridge to his app, but had not set the connection string for the cartridge in Keystone.

If this is your case as well you need to set the Keystone `mongo` option in `Keystone.init()` or using `Keystone.set('mongo', 'connection_sring')`. When you created the cartridge you got a url and some credentials. OpenShit passes these to your application in environment variables. You can build the mongo connection string as follows:

```
var connectionString = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + '/' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;

keystone.set('mongo', connectionString);

or 

keystone.init({
  ...
  mongo: connectionString,
  ...
});
```

Or you can use `rhc set-env` to set the `MONGO` environment variable as follows:

```
rhc set-env MONGO=http://{username}:{password}@{connection url}/{dbname} -a your_app_name
```

The `connection url` above is the one you got from OpenShift when you created the cartridge. If looks like a standard MONGODB url (e.g. `mongodb://127.6.85.129:27017/`).

These are just my best guesses, given that your question is a bit thin on details. You may want to post some more specifics so we can more accurately assess your problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply, wasn't really sure what to put I am just using a fresh copy of keystone.js with no cloudinary

Comment: I am thinking the issue is with connecting to mongo, I added the mongo cartridge but not sure if I need to specify the database credentials anywhere or whether open shift does this automatically.

Comment: Cool thanks, I changed the string around a little based on another example but it works.  if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
  console.log('if');
  var connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
  keystone.set('mongo', connection_string);
}

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for the update. I'll update my answers so others in the future can benefit from it.